# SMTP ERROR Failed to connect to server A connection attempt failed

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

I have a problem sending an email and this is the error:

```
Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()

Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com:587 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond properly after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond properly after a period of time, or the established connection failed because the connected host failed to respond. (10060)
```

I've adjusted the one on https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting and it's still an error, can someone help me please?

```
public function Approve1($id) 
{  
    // For database
    $data = $this->ApprovalModel->requisition_approval(array('hod'=>'submit'),$id);
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
    // PHPMailer object
    $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $email=$this->uri->segment(4);
    $response = false;
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
    // SMTP configuration
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'xyz@gmail.com';   
    $mail->Password = 'xyz';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    $mail->Port = 587; 
    $mail->setFrom('xyz@gmail.com', 'xxx');
    $mail->addAddress($email); 
    $mail->Subject = 'hii!'; 
    $mail->isHTML(true); 
    // Email body content
    $loginlink = site_url() . 'login' . '"';
    $mailContent = <<<HEREDOC
        Dear Sir/Madam ,
        Your staff asked for Manpower Request, please click this link for your approval $loginlink
        <p>Thank you,</p>
        <p>Cladtek HRIS</p>
        HEREDOC;
    $mail->Body = $mailContent; 
    // Send email
    if(!$mail->send()){
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else{ 
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> Submit Succesfully!<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>');
        return redirect('home/manage_data');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is described exactly in the troubleshooting guide. It's most likely that your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP, so read their docs and policies, ask them if they will remove that block, or find a new hosting provider.